# Overloaded UPS, might it have damaged connected hardware?

Tags: power-supply, power, ups

I have an APC Back-UPS ES 400, and during a brief power failure (less than a minute), its buzzer sounded continuously. Looking up the manual, this apparently indicates an overload. It's rated to 240W, and it's definitely plausible that the computer connected to it could exceed that since it was running a game (maybe 10 to 20W over by my estimate; I can't measure it).

The buzzer stopped when power was resumed, and the PC still works fine, but I'm slightly paranoid now that this could have damaged the PSU or other components.

Comment: The answer is may be. If you overload the UPS, the UPS will provide less/unstable power then expected,  which may damage hardware

Comment: @Bilo That makes sense, although I'd like to see confirmation one way or the other. Fortunately the computer's PSU is of high quality and wasn't loaded near its limit.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK all UPSs sound off when the power fails. I have dual monitors but only #1 is connected to the UPS. Never a printer or scanner, I presume you know this.

Comment: No, its usual power failure sound is a two-tone alarm every few seconds. It's never made the continuous beep sound before. Only the computer system was connected, no monitors or peripherals.

Comment: UPS batteries last from 3 to 5 yrs. I've run one with a bad battery, doesn't provide anything but surge protection that way. You could test the UPS without involving your comp by using light bulbs/ fixtures.

Comment: I don't think the battery is bad- although I've had the unit for a while, the battery hasn't been called upon too many times or for very long each time. And it did still provide power during the failure despite the long beep. Testing it is a good idea, but I don't want to unnecessarily stress it and possibly reduce its life further.